# web browser exits after a few hours

Tags: browser, bugs, kiosk-mode

I wanted to use an Android tablet for a browser-based info frame, displaying an autorefreshing page. I installed a program that disables screen timeout / blanking, I set the webpage as the homepage, I just need to click "browser" on startup and...

...and about 2 hours I'm back to desktop. Browser quits all by itself. The webpage code is fairly trivial, little chance for any memory leaks (simply reloading the target URL of an image inside a function launched with `setInterval()` ) and there is no manual intervention of any kind or any other activity performed by the tablet.

Is there any way either to keep the browser from quitting, or to have it restarted in case it does?

The tablet runs Android 2.3.3 (or thereabouts) and can't be upgraded to anything newer - it's a fairly obscure model with no rooting procedures available and the manufacturer doesn't provide any higher upgrades.

Comment: You might have to install the Android development tools on your desktop machine and look at the log output to see why the browser is quitting.

Comment: @DanHulme: I have the dev tools, but where's that log located?

Comment: Use `adb logcat` to see it.